# Use libraries installed by R for other programs?

Tags: python, r, unix

When R installs a package that contains other programs/libraries (e.g., `hdf5`, `SQLite`), can I use those in other programs? For instance, I have `hdf5.so` installed in `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/2.13/Resources/library/hdf5/libs/x86_64/` - can I use this instead of installing `hdf5` for use by Python (`h5py`, etc.?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a general rules, no.  You also may be misreading this: `hdf5.so` is the *binding* from R to the hdf5 libraries.  E.g. when (on a Linux box) I ask the linker what a given R library links to, I get something like

```
edd@max:~$ ldd /usr/lib/R/site-library/XML/libs/XML.so 
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffcbf75000)
        libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fc0a1514000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc0a12fc000)
        libR.so => /usr/lib/libR.so (0x00007fc0a0d92000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc0a09fe000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc0a07fa000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc0a0574000)
        libblas.so.3gf => /usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas/libblas.so.3gf (0x00007fc09fcff000)
        libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007fc09fa1b000)
        libreadline.so.6 => /lib/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fc09f7d8000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fc09f59c000)
        liblzma.so.2 => /usr/lib/liblzma.so.2 (0x00007fc09f37a000)
        libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007fc09f169000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc09ef61000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fc09ed53000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc09eb34000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc0a1ab6000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fc09e91e000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fc09e6d9000)
edd@max:~$
```

indicating that R's XML package itself depends on libxml2.

So instead of providing the libraries you are looking for, these often just link to them too.

Comment: +1 Becoming familiar with `ldd` is a wise idea.  I have used it to debug a bunch of R <-> externalLibrary.so issues.

Comment: I see... but the original libraries that these `.so` files link to, can they not be used by other programs?

Comment: The fact that they are *linked in* demonstrates that they are in effect *used by other programs* as R is _(an)other program_ to the XML library.